# Network with Radial Gradient Fill Nodes

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, visualization, charts

I would like to put a radial gradient effect on the nodes of a network. As far as I can tell *Mathematica* does not support radial gradient fill effects for graphics primitives.  One way to get the radial gradient effect is with [concentric circles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72569/how-to-create-a-disk-with-smoothly-changing-coloring/72571#72571), and a few other alternatives that I've found around the net.  I made my own version using a triangular polygon that is rotated and it tends to give smoother gradients at the expense of ragged edges, but those are transparent for these applications so it works nicely.

Unfortunately, I can't get the graphics object to scale at all, and it's supposed to scale by the radius property.  Also, the only way I could figure out how to get the nodes to be the shapes is to set the `VertexShapeFunction` for each node separately using `Properties`.  In the sample below I've only done this for the second node, but I could build a table of these if that's the only way to set it.

```
TheGraph=RandomGraph[{5, 8}];
TheNodeColors={Red,Green,Blue,Purple,Orange};
TheNodeSizes={1,2,3,4,5};

GradientFillNode[theColor_:grey,theRadius_:1,NumberOfSlices_:40]:=Graphics[Table[Polygon[{{0,0},{theRadius*Cos[2Pi t/NumberOfSlices],theRadius*Sin[2Pi t/NumberOfSlices]},{theRadius*Cos[2Pi (t+1)/NumberOfSlices],theRadius*Sin[2Pi (t+1)/NumberOfSlices]}},VertexColors->{theColor,Opacity[0,theColor],Opacity[0,theColor]}],{t,NumberOfSlices}]];

NodeImages=Table[GradientFillNode[TheNodeColors[[i]],TheNodeSizes[[i]],40],{i,Length[TheNodeColors]}]

ColoredGraph=Graph[TheGraph,VertexShapeFunction->(Inset[NodeImages[[1]],#]&),ImageSize->500,Properties->{2->{VertexShapeFunction->(Inset[NodeImages[[2]],#]&)}}]
```

As you can see if you run it, this does change the color of the second node, but the sizes are all the same.

(1) How do I get the nodes to size according to my setting?

(2) Is there a better way to use the `VertexShapeFunction` to have it color and size the nodes properly?

(3) Is there an entirely different and better way to achieve nodes with a radial color gradient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very rough attempt:

```
gradDisk[cent_?VectorQ, rad_?NumericQ, col_?ColorQ, n_Integer: 30] :=
    {Texture[RadialGradientImage[{Append[Darker[col], 1], Append[col, 1/2], 
                                  Append[Lighter[col], 0]}]], 
     Polygon[N[CirclePoints[cent, rad, n]], 
             VertexTextureCoordinates -> N[CirclePoints[{1, 1}/2, 1/2, n]]]}

BlockRandom[SeedRandom["somegraph"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            gr = RandomGraph[{5, 8}]; 
            sizes = RandomSample[Range[5]/5]; 
            cols = RandomSample[{Red, Green, Blue, Purple, Orange}];]

Graph[gr, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Gray], 
      VertexShapeFunction -> 
      Thread[Range[5] -> Map[Function[c, gradDisk[#1, Mean[#3]/2, c] &], cols]], 
      VertexSize -> Thread[Range[5] -> sizes], VertexStyle -> EdgeForm[]]
```

[image: graph with radial gradient nodes]

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the built-in `ChartElementFunction` `"GradientBubble"` as a `VertexShapeFunction` as follows:

```
ClearAll[vShapeF];
vShapeF[cs_: "Rainbow", gd_: "Radial"] := ChartElementDataFunction["GradientBubble", 
  "ColorScheme" -> cs, "GradientDirection" -> gd][
   Transpose[Function[t, # + t #3/2] /@ {-1, 1}], {1}] &;
```

Using `gr`, `sizes` and `cols` from J.M.'s answer:

```
Graph[gr, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Gray], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> {v_ :>  vShapeF[Lighter[cols[[v]], #] & /@ Subdivide[4]], 
   1 -> vShapeF["CoffeeTones"]}, 
 VertexSize -> {v_ :> sizes[[v]]}]
```

[image]

Use

```
VertexShapeFunction -> {v_ :> 
   vShapeF[Opacity[1 - #, cols[[v]]] & /@ Rest[Subdivide[5]]]}
```

to get

[image]

Use the optional second argument to change the direction of the gradient:

```
Graph[gr, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Gray], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> {v_ :> 
    vShapeF[Lighter[cols[[v]], #] & /@ Subdivide[4], "DescendingRadial"], 
   1 -> vShapeF["CoffeeTones", "DescendingRadial"]}, 
 VertexSize -> {v_ :> sizes[[v]]}]
```

[image]